# Inserting rows of varying lengths to Postgres with pyscopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am building multiple different pandas dataframes in a for loop, which have a different number of columns depending what data is available from a website I am scraping.

The issue I am having is when I loop over the rows of the dataframe  at the end of the initial loop to insert them into postgres using psycopg2, the length of the column names and the number of rows change for each loop, meaning I need a dynamic query. A set number of the columns will always be there and are of type character and the columns which may/may not be there are all of type numeric.

This is what I have already tried:

```
con = pypg.connect(user = pg_user, password = pg_pass,
                   host = "pg_host", database = "db",
                   port = "5432")

cursor = con.cursor()

# dt = pandas dataframe with n columns
cols = [i for i in dt.columns if i not in ["column1","column2","column3"]] 

# these columns are always in dt, want to convert others to numeric

for col in cols:
    dt[col]=pd.to_numeric(dt[col])

# Build the string insertion vectors for the correct number of columns
col_insert = "%s, %s, %s,"
data_insert = "%s, %s, %s,"

sql_colnames = tuple(dt.columns)

for i in range(1, (len(sql_colnames) - 2), 1):
  if i != (len(sql_colnames) - 3):
    data_insert = data_insert + " %d,"
    col_insert = col_insert + " %s,"
  elif i == (len(sql_colnames) - 3):
       data_insert = data_insert + " %d"
       col_insert = col_insert + " %s"

# Iterate through the rows of the dataframe and insert them into postgres
for index, row in all_odds_dt.iterrows():
    row_ = tuple(row)
    qry_data = sql_colnames + row_prices
    qry = "INSERT INTO odds_portal_prices (" + col_insert + ") VALUES(" + data_insert + ")" % qry_data

cursor.execute(qry)
```

The error I receive when I try and run the query is

```
  File "<ipython-input-351-14d7e958b2a7>", line 4, in <module>
    qry = "INSERT INTO odds_portal_prices (" + col_insert + ") VALUES(" + data_insert + ")" % qry_data
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have checked the lengths of the `qry_data` vector to ensure it matches with the number of elements in the `col_insert` and `data_insert` combined.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With parameterization, you can streamline much of your processing without worrying about string formatting of values between the string and numeric types. However, the preferred `str.format` is used to build prepared statement but only once outside of any loop.

Note: the parameter placeholder for psycopg2 is `%s` which is not to be confused with the Python string formatting symbols of `%s` and `%d`.

```
### CONVERT NUMERIC COLUMNS WITH apply()
num_cols = dt.columns.difference(["column1","column2","column3"]).values
dt[num_cols] = dt[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)

### BUILD PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
sql = ("INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_Photo ({sql_cols}) VALUES ({placeholders})"
         .format(sql_cols = ", ".join([i for i in dt.columns]), 
                 placeholders = ", ".join(["%s" for i in dt.columns]))
      )

# EXECUTE PARAMETERIZED QUERY BINDING DF VALUES
cursor.executemany(sql, dt.values.tolist())   
con.commit()
```

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. I was under the impression from reading other answers on this site that there wasn't a method for uploading a whole pandas dataframe to postgres at once and it had to be done iteratively in a loop. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your literal and immediate issue is with the way the line on which your formatting takes place breaks down. If I expand it to use some temporary variables it actually happens like this:

```
qry1 = "INSERT INTO odds_portal_prices ("
qry2 = ") VALUES("
qry3 = ")" % qry_data
qry = qry1 + col_insert + qry2 + data_insert + qry3
```

Since there are no formatting points in the string `")"` all formatting arguments are not used.

*However*, this is not the best way to dynamically construct a SQL statement. I would recommend first separating building the statement with the columns from the values. Then use the `vars` argument to the cursor's `execute` function to safely get the parameters into the query. See [the related psycopg documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) for more details.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I simply set ```qry = qry1 + qry2 + qry3``` then ```qry = qry % qry_data``` it should solve my issue. I will look into implementing it in the way you have suggested, as it did seem long winded approaching it the way I did. Thanks.

Comment: Reconsider this string concatenation approach for its readability, maintainability, and possibly safety should web data have malicious SQL!

Comment: @MichaelPyle I'm not suggesting that you do it like that. Like Parfait I think you would be better off letting the cursor handle the data safely. That expansion is meant to highlight the source of the Python error.